# How to request administrator rights?

Tags: javascript, node.js, permissions, exe, pkg

How do I ask for admin rights when executing the code for this code?
For example, I have a program that creates a shortcut to a directory and it will be compiled via pkg into an .exe file:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

fs.symlink(path.resolve("path/to/directory"), path.resolve("path/to/shortcut"), console.log);
```

Maybe there is some library or something else to request these rights directly from the code, or something else?